# Deleting random subset of observations within a group of variables that have a certain value

Tags: r

Let's suppose that I have a data frame where I would like to remove a random sample of observations (meaning, the entire row) that meet a certain criterion.  Take this dataframe as an example:

```
id    var1  var2
AAAA  1     Car
BBBB  2     Truck
CCCC  1     Boat
DDDD  2     Car
EEEE  1     Truck
FFFF  2     Car
FFFF  2     Car
FFFF  2     Car
FFFF  2     Car
```

How would one go about (1) taking a random sample (n=3) of observations where `var2=="Car"`, and (2) deleting all other rows where `var2=="Car"` that were not sampled? I'm having trouble using `sample()` within a certain criterion (i.e. "var2=Car") because it also removes all of the other observations from the dataset (when I want to keep the other rows with `Trucks` and `Boats`)

Comment: will the sample() command help?

Comment: The tricky part I'm finding is that sampling within a certain criterion (i.e. "var2=Car") also removes all of the other observations from the dataset -- I want to keep the other rows with `Trucks` and `Boats`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regarding the difficulty you are encountering while using `sample`, it might have to do with what/where you are sampling from.

You don't want to sample from the data.frame directly, as that will sample the columns

You don't want to sample from a logical vector, as using the results to further index the data.frame is less than straightforward.

Instead, you want to sample from *the indexes to the rows*.  You can sample from the appropriate subset of the index, then combine with a second subset, but that is cumbersome.

#### Much more straightforward is to *sample what you will take out*:

```
# remove 3 random rows where var2 is "car": 
DT[-sample(which(var2=="Car"), 3)]

#      id var1  var2
# 1: BBBB    2 Truck
# 2: CCCC    1  Boat
# 3: DDDD    2   Car
# 4: EEEE    1 Truck
# 5: FFFF    2   Car
# 6: FFFF    2   Car
```

*Where `DT <- data.table(yourDataFrame)`*

Notice the use of `which( )` to give indexes to the rows.  Without, I would have been sampling from a vector of `TRUE` & `FALSE` (which, thanks to `recycling` would give very unpredictable results).

Answer (score 3):

```
(carindex <- which(dat$var2 == 'Car'))
(deleteindex <- sample(carindex, length(carindex) - 3)) 
dat[-deleteindex, ]

R > (carindex <- which(dat$var2 == 'Car'))
[1] 1 4 6 7 8 9
R > (deleteindex <- sample(carindex, length(carindex) - 3))
[1] 4 6 9
R > dat[-deleteindex, ]
    id var1  var2
1 AAAA    1   Car
2 BBBB    2 Truck
3 CCCC    1  Boat
5 EEEE    1 Truck
7 FFFF    2   Car
8 FFFF    2   Car
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `data.table`. `.I` is a vector containing the row numbers for a particular subset. (see `?data.table`)

```
library(data.table)
# assuming your data.frame is called df
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[DT[, list(keep =  if(var2 =='Car'){
   .I[sample(.N, 3)]
   } else{.I})  ,  by = var2]$keep]

     id var1  var2
1: DDDD    2   Car
2: FFFF    2   Car
3: AAAA    1   Car
4: BBBB    2 Truck
5: EEEE    1 Truck
6: CCCC    1  Boat
```