# Delete random subsets of variables within a group that have certain values with a list

Tags: r

This is a slight variation on the question [Deleting random subset of observations within a group of variables that have a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159828/deleting-random-subset-of-observations-within-a-group-of-variables-that-have-a-c).
The variation I am looking for is how to delete subsets of rows where the number of rows removed changes each time the grouping criteria changes.  Here is a simple example data set with a column of numeric values and a numeric grouping column (grouping column can also be a factor like "AA1", "AA2", etc).

```
set.seed(23)
df<-data.frame(a=round(rnorm(500,mean=20,sd=2)))
df$group<-seq(from = 1, to = length (df),by=5)
```

A table of the data (table(df$a) gives this result:

```
group: 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
count:  1  7 13 24 65 87 91 91 59 42 12  8
```

For example:  When the grouping value is equal to 15, I want to randomly remove 4 rows; when group = 16, randomly remove 7 rows; when group = 17, randomly remove 7 rows.  This process continues for each grouping variable.

Here is my current solution:

```
(dfindex<-which(df$a==15)) ##create index that meets the grouping variable criteria
(delete.df.index<-sample(dfindex,4)) ##select number of rows to randomly remove
dfnew<-df[-delete.df.index,] ##create a new data frame and delete the randomly selected rows
```

Repeate steps from above on the newly created data frame:

```
(dfindex<-which(dfnew$a==16)) ##create another index from the grouping variable criteria 
(delete.df.index<-sample(dfindex,3)) ##select rows to randomly delete
dfnew<-dfnew[-delete.df.index,] ##delete rows
```

Repeate for each combination of grouping variable and randomly selected rows to remove.

```
(dfindex<-which(dfnew$a==17))
(delete.df.index<-sample(dfindex,7))
dfnew<-dfnew[-delete.df.index,]
```

With this example, I have 12 grouping levels.  The simple but time consuming approach is to copy/paste/and edit the code for each combination of grouping variable and row removal. I was wondering if it would be possible to use a table (or something similar) to specify the grouping values and number of rows to remove for that specific grouping variable:

Example table of groups and rows to remove.

```
Group  Number of rows to randomly remove
14          0
15          4
16          3
17          7
18          40
19          23
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, why not use a `for` loop? I.e. scan the rows in the last table you've provided like `dfnew$a==Group[i]` `sample(dfindex,Numberofrows[i])`. And, also, you might want to save your `dfnew`s in a list, i.e. `mylist[[i]] <- dfnew`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this -

```
set.seed(23)
df<-data.frame(a=round(rnorm(50,mean=20,sd=2)))

# create table of no of rows that need to be removed per each a
noofrowsremove <- read.table(textConnection(
'a toremove
21 1  
23 2  
15 2  
17 1  
19 2  
20 2  
24 2  
16 1
22 1
18 3'), header = TRUE)

library(data.table)

# assign random number in a new column, this will help in sampling
df$tosample <- runif(50)

# convert data.frame to data.table, grouped operations are easier on data.table
dt <- data.table(df)
# rank the tosample column within each unique a value
dt[,samplerank := rank(tosample), by = 'a']
# merge the filtering no of rows with dt
dt <- merge(dt,noofrowsremove, by = 'a')
# filter out rows that have samplerank columns <= the no of rows that need to be removed
dttrimmed <- dt[samplerank > toremove]
```

Comment: Thanks @Codoremifa this works perfectly.  I would up vote this answer, but I am a new user and do not have enough reputation points.  Consider this an upvote!

Comment: @feldhauj - no problem. You can consider accepting the answer though by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After working through the answer provided by Codoremifa, I noticed a few small details that might be worth documenting for others that find this post. Using the answer provided by Codoremifa, I made a few small changes and included a little extra code to illustrate a few important details. Basically, pay attention to the merge step and decide how to handle the NA values generated by the merge step.

```
set.seed(23)
df<-data.frame(a=round(rnorm(50,mean=20,sd=2)))

# create table of no of rows that need to be removed per each a
noofrowsremove <- read.table(textConnection(
 'a toremove
21 0  

17 1  
19 2  
20 2  
24 2  
16 1
22 1
18 3'), header = TRUE)

##excluded values 23 and 15 from the above df to illustrate an example below
#Keep value 21 and just assigned it a 0 (i.e., do not remove any values of 21).

library(data.table)

# assign random number in a new column, this will help in sampling
df$tosample <- runif(50) #can also use runif(nrow(df))

# convert data.frame to data.table, grouped operations are easier on data.table
dt <- data.table(df)

# rank the tosample column within each unique a value
dt[,samplerank := rank(tosample), by = 'a']

# merge the filtering no of rows with dt.  Be careful with merge options.
dt1 <- merge(dt,noofrowsremove, by = 'a') #46 rows
dt2 <- merge(dt,noofrowsremove, by = 'a',all=TRUE) #51 rows. 

#Notice slight differences in the number of rows between dt1 and dt2 
#In dt2, value 23 in the toremove column is "NA" because 23 was not included in noofrowsremove
nrow(dt1) #46 rows
nrow(dt2) #51 rows

##to keep values with "NA" change the "NA" to a 0
dt2$toremove[is.na(dt2$toremove)] <- 0 #assign NA to 0

# filter out rows that have samplerank columns <= the no of rows that need to be removed
dttrimmed1 <- dt1[samplerank > toremove] #36 rows.  toremove values with NA are exlcuded
dttrimmed2 <- dt2[samplerank > toremove] #40 rows.  Kept values with NA reasigned to 0
```